# IFTTT Maker Filter for Twitter URL

Tags: javascript, twitter, ifttt, pocket

One of my favorite IFTTT recipes is to save the links from Tweets that I favorite to my Pocket account. Unfortunately, the default recipe for this also saves the text of Tweets I favorite that don't have links. Recently IFTT offered a new "maker" account which lets you create "filters" that can avoid problems like this. Theoretically it is possible to create a Maker Recipe with a filter so that only Tweets linking to an external URL are saved to Pocket. The problem is, to do this you have to know how to program in Javascript. I tried learning by copying some examples, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work properly. Hopefully someone here would like to have the same thing and might be willing to help write such a filter?

Comment: Can you provide links to the example(s) you were trying to build off of?

Comment: I just used the ones available in the [documentation](https://platform.ifttt.com/docs/applets#using-filter-code). There is additional [documentation](https://platform.ifttt.com/maker/guide#filter-code) and [sample templates](https://platform.ifttt.com/maker/_/applets/templates) elsewhere. (A bit confusing, as they seem to have two different documentation pages?)